# Octave random Rational Numbers gernrator

Tags: random, octave, rational-numbers

I just start to study about Octave and I have a question about getting Rational Numbers.

I just check

> http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Random-Number-Generation.html#Random-Number-Generation

this page to learn the way to get random Rational Numbers.
for example..

if we use rand(1, 3.1)

i would like to get random number between 1 and 3.1 (like 2.34)

However, i am not really sure about function that i have to use..

can you give some example ?

thanks

Comment: your interpretation is wrong. `rand (1, 3.1)` will give you matrix of size `1x3` (numbers seem to be truncated) with random values in the interval `[0 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `unifrnd` returns random numbers sampled from a uniform distribution.  The first two arguments determine the lower and upper bounds.  The remaining (optional) arguments determine the shape of the result.  So, for example, to get random numbers between 1 and 3.1:

```
octave:12> unifrnd(1, 3.1)
ans =  2.4990
octave:13> unifrnd(1, 3.1)
ans =  3.0240
octave:14> unifrnd(1, 3.1, 2, 3)
ans =

   1.8929   2.9675   2.1239
   2.4756   2.6172   1.6197
```

(The results are regular [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers.  I don't understand why you are asking about [*rational* numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number).)